# Rotate a small wheel using magnets

Tags: electromagnetism

I know this question already asked so much times.

I tried to rotate a wheel by placing few magnets on it. And I used some powerful magnet and repel it using opposite poles in the magnets placed in a wheel.

Thing is I got rotation for a while upto next magnet in the wheel. Only issue I get is the first magnet repels and make some movement in the wheel. When second magnet coming, it doesn't enter the repelling magnet position. Any idea to overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do would "break the laws of physics" if it worked.
You can't, so it doesn't.

As the system rotates there will be losses. Air drag and friction and more.
These losses absorb energy and cause things to slow down. For a system to rotate indefinitely it must get energy from somewhere. If there is no input energy it must make its own. A basic law of physics says that energy cannot be created. Millions of people have tried to do so. So far, all have failed and there is good reason to think that all will always do so - at least within the systems that we have access to.

George Box is known for his statement that "All models are wrong,. Some models are useful." Applying an imperfect but useful model to how magnets behave helps us to understand them better.

Most of the confused ideas about trying to achieve constant rotation and "free energy" from magnets comes from trying to visualise them as energy sources. The model of a magnet as an energy source in its own right is not only wrong but not at all useful.

An imperfect but better model is to consider magnets as if they interacted as "springs".
Here I'll use the concept of sprinfs pressing against and repelling each other. The concept of attraction can also be used but I'll not do so here.

With the spring model two magnets in proximity with the same polarity are like two compressed springs pressing against each other. If one is on a wheel (W1) and one is attached to a stationary surface(S1), if you turn the wheel slightly the two springs repel each other and the wheel turns.   As the springs push the magnets apart energy is stored in the rotating wheel as it accelerates.

As the rotating magnet (W1) approaches a second stationary magnet (S2) the "springs" compress against each other.
If the second stationary magnet S2 is less strong (lower spring constant say) than was the first stationary magnet S1 then W1 may be able to close the gap so the magnets are opposite, slowing as it does as the "springs" compress without the wheel stopping fully, and then move past S2 and accelerate again. Similarly ot may encounter S3. I S3 is less strong than S1 it can again ":compress the spring", slow down, move up to and then past S3 and again accelerate. After one turn it again comes to S1.
Now we know that S2 is as strong as S1 :-)
When W1 comes towards S1 aand the "springs" compress the amount of force that W1 is able to exert, and the energy stored in the wheel, can at best be the same as when it started. If there have been ANY losses it will not be able to get all the way back to the start. In a truly lossless system it would JUST get back to the start.
If it was given some external spin initially it may be able to pass S1 as the extra energy to do so was imparted externally.
If you observed this system you would see a wheel rotating and deceleating as magnets came into proximity and then accelerating as they passed each other. It may LOOK as if the system was operating as a motor.
However, you would really be seeing the "spring model" above, and in due course the losses would cause it to stop.

You can find MANY device on the internet that appear to work using magnets and rotation and not to ever stop. Every one, every single one, is a fake.

Many years ago I saw a demonstration of a system that was made with ball bearings and a circular tilted track - ball bearings APPEARED to run around the track forever without external energy input. It was something like the ball bearing analogy of the above spring model. What they did was to very slowly revolve the whole track with a hidden motor to make up for the losses. It was very good and very convincing. But, still a fake.

Comment: Thanks for all your useful responses. But is there monopole magnets are exist?. Is the same concept (just for rotation purpose) can be achieved through mono pole magnet? (if exists)

Comment: @user3391693 Theory says that monopoles may have been created as part o the early creation of the universe. They MAY exist 'somewhere out there' put quite possibly not, and "we" have not got them. Sadly. Very useful indeed they would be. You can do some clever magnetic things with superconductors (search Meissner affect) but even that does not give either net energy gain. I'd love it to be true, but everything like that you ever see is fake. Always. BUT - the good news is that electronics (and Physics and engineering generally) is utterly chock full of other fun exciting interesting stuff .

Comment: **Meissner effect** - [**awesome images**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=meissner+effect&biw=853&bih=525&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI_Z7s76v7xgIVxiOUCh0Vwguz#tbm=isch&q=meissner+effect+jpg) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect)

Answer (score 0):

See Russell McMahon's answer.  Such a device may not work at all, and if it does work it will do so for only a limited time.

However, if you want to give it another chance, the magnets you attached to your fan blades may be too thick.  The magnet you hold to repel the blades may work for one magnet, but when the next magnet comes too close, the magnetic fields from the sides of the fan-blade magnets are broken by the propulsion magnet and "cog", and the whole mechanism freezes.  Also, be certain that all the magnets have the same pole facing outward.  At most, you may be able to get it to spin for a short time.

Magnetic fields are not like searchlights.  They extend from all sides of a magnet.  Look at this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiAhiu6UqXQ.  The claims are false.  There are many ways it could be faked.

This mechanism is NOT a source of "free energy".  Even if it works at all, the magnets eventually will become demagnetized.  It's analogous to using a battery to power something.  When you drain the power source, the power stops.

Comment: NO! It will not work at all.Essentially

Comment: @Russell McMahon: Maglev propulsion works if polarity of the guidance magnets is switched frequently: https://khastroleague.wordpress.com/maglev-technology-how-it-works/.  Whether a fan blade device will work is questionable, but take a look at the demo video link in the answer - it doesn't look fake.

Comment: It's a fake. There is absolutely no doubt about it. How it is faked is not 100% obvious but it's 90%+ obvious. I would have no problem at all faking convincingly this or any other "free energy device I have ever seen portrayed. What is not obvious is why quack charlatan scumbags like Mr Horse Radish bother doing what they do. They are a net drain on the resources of humanity. SOME people who propose "free" energy devices really believe what they say and are fooled by a lack of understanding. But Mr sadastheygo is just a huckster - he KNOWS that it does not work. Sadly.

Comment: YES! Maglev works a treat - I love it. I have ridden the Shanghai China Maglev at over 400 kph on a number of occasions and love it every time. BUT the system uses net energy and cannot achieve either suspension or propulsion with static magnets. (You can get unstable static suspension with permanent magnets and stabilise it with an outside force so you get static suspension with no energy input - but that fits my 'spring model" well and is not what the Youtube hucksters are pedalling. Such people are evil - as a demo like that one MUSt be faked and he must know. You can have ....

Comment: .... batteries in the fan, batteries in the light bulb, magnetic induction through the table etc. I personally could do magnetic induction from a shirt sleeve if I wished to. (I hold an (expired) US patent for IPT( Inductive power transfer) and 1st met IPT in 1973! (I'm old :-) ). I've being 'playing' with electronics for over 50 years [!] and would love even 1% of these systems to be genuine. NONE are and none will be when taking the path that all take. Sadly. It's no proof of anything but [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/3288/russell-mcmahon) is a sampler of my experience

Comment: @Russell McMahon: Thank you !  I will edit the answer and reference your comments.